# While connecting from Mongo Client in Windows VM to Mongodb 4.4 in Mac host OS, receiving "Timed out after 5000 ms while waiting to connect"

Tags: mongodb, macos, virtual-machine, robo3t, studio3t

Mongodb 4.4.14 is intalled in Mac OS Monterey version 12.4.

Connection from Robo 3T installed in Mac itself works.
Connection from mongo cli in mac itself also works:

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.4.14
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("ab8018b3-c4f2-4236-8c3b-abef5468bb03") }
MongoDB server version: 4.4.14
---
The server generated these startup warnings when booting: 
        2022-06-02T15:59:13.574+05:30: Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted
---
MongoDB Enterprise >
```

While connecting from Studio 3T installed in Windows Virtual Machine (it is Parallels software, NOT VirtualBox) to this mongodb 4.4, receiving the following error:

```
Connection failed.

SERVER [192.168.1.2:27017] (Type: UNKNOWN) CONNECTING

Details:
Timed out after 5000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=192.168.1.2:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]
```

Note that the Mac host IP address is 192.168.1.2. And ping from Windows VM to Mac works fine. Also disabled the firewall in Windows.

```
C:\Windows\system32>ping 192.168.1.2

Pinging 192.168.1.2 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.2: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.2: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.2: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.2: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.2:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

C:\Windows\system32>
```

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the parallels software network configuration, selected "[Shared Network (Recommended)](https://kb.parallels.com/4948#section1)" and it worked fine.